# C bitshifting behavior

Tags: c

I found this example, can anyone explain what's going on here? I'm using LLVM 7.1.

```
uint8_t a = 0xff;
a = ~a >> 1;
// a = 0b1000000

uint8_t b = 0xff;
b = ~b;
b = b >> 1;
//b = 0
```

`a` and `b` should be equal??

EDIT:
Added the disassembly:

```
testt`main:
    0x100000f70 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x100000f71 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100000f74 <+4>:  xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x100000f76 <+6>:  movl   $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
    0x100000f7d <+13>: movl   %edi, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x100000f80 <+16>: movq   %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x100000f84 <+20>: movb   $-0x1, -0x11(%rbp)
    0x100000f88 <+24>: movzbl -0x11(%rbp), %edi
    0x100000f8c <+28>: xorl   $-0x1, %edi
    0x100000f8f <+31>: sarl   $0x1, %edi
    0x100000f92 <+34>: movb   %dil, %cl
    0x100000f95 <+37>: movb   %cl, -0x11(%rbp)
    0x100000f98 <+40>: movb   $-0x1, -0x12(%rbp)
    0x100000f9c <+44>: movzbl -0x12(%rbp), %edi
    0x100000fa0 <+48>: xorl   $-0x1, %edi
    0x100000fa3 <+51>: movb   %dil, %cl
    0x100000fa6 <+54>: movb   %cl, -0x12(%rbp)
    0x100000fa9 <+57>: movzbl -0x12(%rbp), %edi
    0x100000fad <+61>: sarl   $0x1, %edi
    0x100000fb0 <+64>: movb   %dil, %cl
    0x100000fb3 <+67>: movb   %cl, -0x12(%rbp)
    0x100000fb6 <+70>: popq   %rbp
    0x100000fb7 <+71>: retq
```

Comment: No, they _should_ not. Implementation defined behaviour. Not enough information given. Have a look at the Assembler output.

Comment: 'a and b should be equal' why?  The code is different.

Comment: @Olaf : Why is it implementation defiend? A right shift of an unsigned integer is fine surely? If it was signed, it would be UB...

Comment: @Jimbo: The shifts are **not** on unsigned integers, but `int`!

Comment: @Olaf... ah I see... they are promoted to int... doh!

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, especially conversion/truncation warnings. A good compiler like gcc will complain.

Comment: @Jimbo: Exactly. Welcome to the wonderful world of C integers :-}

Comment: @Olaf: Yes... wonderful indeed :) One of those little subtleties that completely slipped my mind :( Thanks to you and Paul R for the clarity :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first case `~a` is promoted to `int`, so you get:

```
a = 0xffffff00 >> 1 = 0x7fffff80
```

which is truncated to `0x80`.

In the second case, the truncation happens *before* the shift, so you get:

```
b = 0xffffff00
```

which is truncated to `0x00`, and then shifting this gives a result of `0x00`.

(Note: the above assumes 32 bit ints, normal 2s complement representation and logical right shifting of signed values.)

Comment: Only for 32 bit `int` (possible) and only for 2's complement (likely). Also, not `~a` is promoted, but `a`. `~` is already done on `int`.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf - I'll add a note to this effect.